# Javascript variable assignment - category wise

Tags: javascript

I added a javascript variable,

model:{}

i want to add data into it in categories like

```
model[id][type1] = data1;
model[id][type2] = data2;
model[id][type3] = data3;
so on..
```

How can i do this in Javascript. We use inheritance in Javascript.

--
Thanks.

Comment: Like that? Not sure what your question is.

Comment: Your question is not clear, what is your code like now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
model[id] = {};
model[id][type1] = data1;
model[id][type2] = data2;
model[id][type3] = data3;
```

Comment: Ok, Thanks. Should i use   model[id] directly..  i mean  no need of  "var" keyword before model.

Comment: Hi Sangram, according to your code `model` is already assigned (it looks like a property of some object), so you wouldn't need the `var` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me.

```
     var model = new Object();
        model["id1"] = {};
        model["id1"]["type1"] = "data1";
        model["id1"]["type2"] = "data2";

        model["id2"] = {};
        model["id2"]["type1"] = "data1";
        model["id2"]["type2"] = "data2";

    alert(model["id1"]["type2"]);
```